# bootstrap secondary navbar not collapsed by default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have secondary navbar in bootstrap navbar and they are no collapsed by default. In other words I want these submenus to be collapsed when page is loaded. Here is my code:

```
<li>
                            <a href="pumpstations.html"><i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i>Pump stations<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a>Create new station</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a>Edit pump station</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a>Test chart</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a>Test Chart</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
```

Comment: What about using dropdown menus?

Comment: this code should be contained by a div which seems like :
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">  and the collapse class should be present in the data-toggle attribute

Comment: @Tony, I tried your solution but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was the problem and it is the link itself it was dummy only without correct href location.